# Twilio number to another twilio number call, gathered text truncated

Tags: twilio-api

We want to build two application using two twilio numbers communicating each other.

Background: one is a chatbot test framework, other is a IVR mock, to help developing the chatbot test framework.

We want to build such a simple call:

1. Number 1 calls Number 2, Number1 waits for answer.
2. Number 2 sends some greetings, and waits for answer
3. Number 1 gots answer, responds, and waits
4. Number 2 gots answer, responds, and waits
5. ...

We have made the applications, they are working wonderful if they are communicating with human. But not with each other.

What we see:

1. Number 1 calls Number 2, Number1 waits for answer.
2. Number 2 sends some greetings, and waits for answer
3. Number 1 gots answer _BUT_TRUNCATED_, responds, and waits
4. Number 2 does not got the answer, twilio sends a call_ended event

We have simplified the situation, reproduced it using two twiml's created by Twilio console:

1. Number 1 calls Number 2, Number1 waits for answer with a simple gather:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Gather input="speech"/>
</Response>
```

2. Number 2 sends Welcome, and waits for answer

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
        <Say>Welcome</Say>
</Response>
```

3. Number 2 gots just "Well"

It is not a Text to Speech, or Speech to Text problem, always the end is truncated (I suppose the gather is not working well, gathers truncates, and TTS gots the truncated voice)

We already tried twilio support, but they are not able to help

Answer (score 0):

Twilio supports just human to twilio conversation. (not twilio to twilio, or machine-voice to twilio conversation)

- verb does not work for twilio to twilio conversation
- verb does not work with  verb in twilio to twilio conversation (Say started earlier somehow as Gather. Adding 1s silence at the start of the say may do the trick)
- verb does not work in twilio to machine-voice conversation. (Reason, workaround not known)

And there can be other problems too. Twilio is planned to Twilio-to-Human conversations.